# Cannot refresh Actionable Message

Tags: adaptive-cards, actionable-notification

my Actionable Message card is not refereshing. Here's what I have already checked

- the refesher card has valid syntax according to the [actionable card designer](https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/)
- the refresher card has the `originator` property

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "originator": "<guid>",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "The action has been recorded."
        }
    ]
}
```

The response is returned as following from the API (Azure Functions)

```cs
string card = "<card-json>";
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CARD-ACTION-STATUS", "Action accepted, thank you.");
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY", "true");
return new OkObjectResult(card);
```

Also I have tried this, without success

```cs
string card = "<card-json>";
req.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CARD-ACTION-STATUS", "Action accepted, thank you.");
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY", "true");
req.HttpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(card));
return new OkResult();
```

When submitting the inital card's POST action, see banner displaying `Action accepted, thank you.` is displayed, however the card itself is not refreshed.

Here's the sample API response data
[image]

Do you spot any obvious mistakes? Researching this behaviour, I've found that the most common error is not supplying the relevant headers, but I was sure to add them.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem myself. I was a data serialization issue.

For creating the adaptive card json I am using these two packages

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AdaptiveCards" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AdaptiveCards.Templating" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Specifically the code is

```cs
string templateFilePath = Path.Combine(ctx.FunctionAppDirectory, "ActionableMessageCards", cardTemplateName);
string template = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(templateFilePath);
var card = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(template);
var context = new EvaluationContext() { Root = cardData };
return card.Expand(context);
```

and `card.Expand()` returns an escaped json-string, i.e. something like this

`"{\"key\": \"value\"}"`

Apparently `return new OkObjectResult(card)` in my question above tries to serialize that string again, resulting in just a string. Which is not `application/json`.

My workaround was to just pass an object rather than a string to the `return new OkObjectResult()` method (*as the name suggests :D*). However, since I do not have types of any card-template I use, I could not use System.Text.Json for deserialization, because this is not supported for anonymous types. Therefore I used Newtonsoft.Json. The following works and updates actionable message as expected.

```
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CARD-ACTION-STATUS", "Action accepted, thank you.");
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY", "true");
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(card);
return new OkObjectResult(obj);
```

Comment: Can you share more on how you did this? I'm experiencing the same thing, but I think it's because I'm not passing the header. I see how you're returning the body of the updated card but how are you returning the headers?

Comment: Hi, I think these are returned implicitly by adding them to the HttpRequest (_req_ in my C# code) object which is a parameter to the function.